# Amazon S3 MultiPartUpload C# not working

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I've been struggling for hours with this problem, I hope you can help me.  Somehow my compiler will only accept InitiateMultipartUploadAsync and not the regular InitiateMultipartUpload and absolutely requires the callback as parameters to compile, but I can figure out what callback function to give him.

```
private static async Task UploadObjectAsync()
{
    // Create list to store upload part responses.
    List<UploadPartResponse> uploadResponses = new List<UploadPartResponse>();
    // Setup information required to initiate the multipart upload.
    InitiateMultipartUploadRequest initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest
    {
        BucketName = "XXXXXXXXX",
        Key = "videos/multipart"
    };

    // Initiate the upload.

    InitiateMultipartUploadResponse initResponse =
        await S3Client.InitiateMultipartUploadAsync(initiateRequest);

    // Upload parts.
    long contentLength = new FileInfo("videotest").Length;
    long partSize = 5 * (long)Math.Pow(2, 20); // 5 MB

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Uploading parts");

        long filePosition = 0;
        for (int i = 1; filePosition < contentLength; i++)
        {
            UploadPartRequest uploadRequest = new UploadPartRequest
            {
                BucketName = "XXXXXXXX",
                Key = "videos/multipart",
                UploadId = initResponse.UploadId,
                PartNumber = i,
                PartSize = partSize,
                FilePosition = filePosition,
                FilePath = "videotest"
            };

            // Track upload progress.
            uploadRequest.StreamTransferProgress +=
                new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(UploadPartProgressEventCallback);

            // Upload a part and add the response to our list.
            uploadResponses.Add(await S3Client.UploadPartAsync(uploadRequest));

            filePosition += partSize;
        }

        // Setup to complete the upload.
        CompleteMultipartUploadRequest completeRequest = new CompleteMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
            Key = "videos/multipart",
            UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
        };
        completeRequest.AddPartETags(uploadResponses);

        // Complete the upload.

        CompleteMultipartUploadResponse completeUploadResponse =
            await S3Client.CompleteMultipartUploadAsync(completeRequest);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An AmazonS3Exception was thrown: {0}", exception.Message);

        // Abort the upload.
        AbortMultipartUploadRequest abortMPURequest = new AbortMultipartUploadRequest
        {
            BucketName = "XXXXXXXXX",
            Key = "videos/multipart",
            UploadId = initResponse.UploadId
        };
        await S3Client.AbortMultipartUploadAsync(abortMPURequest);
    }
}
public static void UploadPartProgressEventCallback(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs e)
{
    // Process event. 
    Console.WriteLine("{0}/{1}", e.TransferredBytes, e.TotalBytes);
}
```

This code was inspired from the offical aws example : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/LLuploadFileDotNet.html  So I really don't understand why this doesn't work !  Currently with above code, Visual Studio is telling me that InitiateMultipartUploadAsync, UploadPartAsync, CompleteMultipartUploadAsync and AbortMultipartUploadAsync all require a callback function, but 1) examples says callback is optional 2) every callback I tried doesn't work.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone else as the same bug, I changed the code completly and used this solution : https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-net/issues/562

Comment: Hi Phil, did this code work for you? I got error `Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type` when I `InitiateMultipartUploadAsync`.

Answer (score 0):

you can initiate it like this:

```
            s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(BUCKETREGION);
            var initiateRequest = new InitiateMultipartUploadRequest { BucketName = BUCKET, Key = KEY };

            await s3Client.InitiateMultipartUploadAsync(initiateRequest).ContinueWith(response =>
              {
                  if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(response.Result.UploadId))
                  {
                      uploadId = response.Result.UploadId;
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      Debug.WriteLine(response.Exception);
                  }
              });
```